# Посчитать среднее диапазона, исключая нулевые значения

Tags: excel

При обработке данных в *Exсel* проявилась странность. 
Работает формула

```
=СРЗНАЧ(ЕСЛИ(A1:A4>0;A1:A4))
```

Но при этом не работает другая

```
=СРЗНАЧ(ЕСЛИ(A1:D1>0;A1:D1))
```

То есть подобная, казалось бы, банальная конструкция - посчитать среднее, исключая из массива нули - не хочет работать со строковыми диапазонами. Это у меня с *Excel* что-то не так или нужно что-то еще сделать?

Comment: у меня наоборот работает в строке, но не  работает в столбце

Comment: и проблема кстати не в `СРЗНАЧ`, а в самом выражении `A1:A4 > 0`  , оно выдет ошибку. Там в экселе можно посмотреть этапы вычисления формулы

Comment: если сделать из `A1:A4` именованный диапазон то будет работать.

Comment: @teran, не поможет. Проблема не в диапазоне, а в его обработке. Но поможет, если поместить в формулу имени всю вложенную функцию.

Comment: @vikttur что значит не поможет, если я проверил в экселе?

Comment: @teran, в ответе объяснил. Вы в первом комментарием писали, что формула у Вас работает в строке. См. рисунок. Попробуйте перенести Вашу формулу в другую ячейку.

Answer (score 1):

С *Excel* все в порядке, но нужно что-то еще сделать :)

Ни первая, ни вторая формулы без этого "чего-то" правильно работать не будут. Бывает, что результат совпадает с ожидаемым, но это совпадение, не более, и в каждом конкретном случае такое совпадение можно объяснить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На рисунке пример. Формулы автора в закрашенных ячейках: в желтых для *A1:A4*, в зеленых для *A1:D1*. Ошибочно думать, что формула будет работать всегда, если она размещена в том же диапазоне строк/столбцов. Это только иллюстрация того, что такие формулы требуют особого обращения.

---

```
=СРЗНАЧ(A1:A4)
```

Тут все понятно - определяем среднее значение диапазона.

В формулах из стартового сообщения нет диапазона. Вернее, из диапазона формируется массив значений. В этом случае это уже не простая формула, а формула, обрабатывающая массив.

Проверим?

```
=СРЗНАЧ(ЕСЛИ(A1:A4>0;A1:A4))
```

В поле для ввода формулы выделяем вложенную функцию с ее содержимым

```
ЕСЛИ(A1:A4>0;A1:A4)
```

нажимаем клавишу `F9`. Что видим? Вместо выделенной части в формуле волшебным образом появился массив констант, состоящий из чисел и логического выражения *ЛОЖЬ*.

Кстати, `F9` (запуск  пересчета) удобно использовать для просмотра работы формулы или поиска ошибки.

- Вот и дошли до "чего-то".

Формула массива вводится тремя клавишами. Находясь в поле ввода формулы (или в режиме редактирования ячейки), нажимаем  `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` - формула должна обрамиться фигурыми скобками. При правке фигурные скобки пропадают, завершать изменения формулы тоже нужно тремя клавишами.

Можно обойтись простой формулой, без "массивного" ввода:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(A1:A4;">0")/СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A1:A4;">0")
```